# spring propagation_requires_new open new hikari connection

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I made a test:

```
--------  Bean A  --------------- 

@Transactional
public void methodA(){
    //some code
    //set or get value in/from DB for example

    otherSpringBean.methodB();
}

--------  Bean B  --------------- 
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void methodB() {

   // some code insert into DB

}
```

I use hikaricp as connection pool, and I set the following hikari params:

```
min idle = 1 connection
max active = 1 connection
```

I always have one and only one connection.

When I run my test (just call `methodA()`), I get a timeout (30 sec by default): methodB could not get a connection.

The Spring documentation say that "Propagation REQUIRES_NEW"

> Create a new transaction, suspend the current transaction if one
>   exists.

Question: Why my first transaction is not suspended? The transaction opened by `methodA()` should be suspended and the connection available for `methodB()`.

Comment: It is suspended but the tdoesn't mean the connection is returned to the pool it cannot even be returned to the pool as that would mean you loose all the changes done (those are tied to a connection).

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean but I tried to set hikari to give me 2 connections and I still have the problem...